# How to pass reference to a WinForm control to a class when creating instance of this class?

Tags: c#, winforms

How to pass a reference to a form object (i.e. TextBox) to a class, so I could specify what text box this instance needs to be working with when creating this instance?
Specific example:
I have a class that processes some text strings. I have few instances of this class.
I also have few text boxes on my form. I have a method in a class that shows some text in a text box. What do I need to do to tell to a specific instance of my class what text box to use when creating this instance? Should be in constructor, something like:

public MyClass (string textString, /*ref to a text box*/)

This is my class:

```
 public class LogClass
{
    private readonly TextBox _textBox;

    private string logText; 
    public string LogText
    {
        get
        {
            return logText;
        }

        set
        {
            logText = value;
        }
    }

    public void AddToLog(string textString)
    {

        try
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(textString))
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("message", nameof(textString));
            }
            logText = logText+ "\n" + textString;
            _textBox.Text = logText;

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }

    }

    public LogClass(string initialText, TextBox textBox)
    {
        logText = initialText;
        _textBox = textBox;
        _textBox.Text = logText;


    }
}
```

And this is my form:

```
 public partial class LogWindow : Form
{

    LogClass myLog = new LogClass("this is initial string", logOutputBox);
    public LogWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public string LogTextToPass {
        get { return logOutputBox.Text; }
        set { logOutputBox.Text = value; }
    }

    private void buttonWriteLog_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        myLog.AddToLog(inputText.Text);

    }

    private void logOutputBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

Error CS0236 is on this line:

```
    LogClass myLog = new LogClass("this is initial string", logOutputBox);
```

Error   CS0236  A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property 'LogWindow.logOutputBox' 
logOutputBox is highlighted

Answer (score 1):

It should be as easy as, passing a reference to it in the [Constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/constructors)

> Whenever a class or struct is created, its constructor is called. A
>   class or struct may have multiple constructors that take different
>   arguments. Constructors enable the programmer to set default values,
>   limit instantiation, and write code that is flexible and easy to read.

```
public class MyLovelyHorse
{
   // private field of TextBox to play with internally
   private readonly TextBox _textbox;


   // constructor
   public MyLovelyHorse(TextBox textbox)
   {
      _textbox = textbox;
   }

   // some awesome method that does stuff
   public void SomeMethodThatDoesStuff()
   {
      _textbox.Text = "rah";
   }
}
```

**Usage**

```
var myLovelyHorse = new MyLovelyHorse(MyTextBox);

// do stuff
myLovelyHorse.SomeMethodThatDoesStuff();
```

Comment: I tried exactly that, but I am getting an error on a line where I create instance of my class: var myLovelyHorse = new MyLovelyHorse(MyTextBox); The error says: A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property 'Form.MyTextBox'

Comment: Sorry, @TheGeneral not used to _Enter_ sending comment, not starting a new line. Updated the comment with error text

Comment: The error code is CS0236. There is this about it but it doesn't tell me much: [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0236)

Comment: @miguello updated, and fixed a typo, you should be able to pass your TextBox into the constructor

Comment: Is the only change in this line:   private **readonly** TextBox _textbox; If so still generates the same error

Comment: @miguello `Form.MyTextBox` i fear you have bigger problems can you paste your code into the question

Comment: @miguello put this in your form constructor instead `myLog = new LogClass("this is initial string", logOutputBox);`

Comment: Ok, now it is taking logOutputBox just fine since it was instantiated. But now when I call myLog in method for button click: `private void buttonWriteLog_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            myLog.AddToLog(inputText.Text);

        }`  it says CS0103 The name myLog does not exist in current context.

Comment: @miguello this is going a little beyond a question, maybe you can paste all your code and your problem into a new question

Comment: With the whole question downvoted I cannot create another question for another day. Thanks anyways. The problem, basically, is that I need a class that I can pass a reference to a Text Box to when I create an instance. So, I could have multiple instances of my class created, each outputting into its own textbox: `LogClass  applesClass = new LogClass("this is log for apples", applesTextBox); LogClass  orangesClass = new LogClass("this is log for oranges", orangesTextBox);` and so on...

Comment: ...and then just add to the corresponding log window by `applesClass.AddToLog("another box of apples just arrived");`

Answer (score 1):

You can pass it in any way you want. A constructor argument seems sensible, if the class isn't useable without a TextBox. In the constructor you can subscribe to the TextBox's events.

```
class TextBoxHandler
{
    private readonly TextBox _textbox;

    public TextBoxHandler(TextBox textbox)
    {
        _textbox = textbox;
        _textbox.Click += HandleClick;
    }

    public void HandleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Do something
    }
}
```